# How to communicate between Fargate services on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have six docker containers all running in their own Tasks (6 tasks), and each task running in a separate Fargate service (6 services) on ECS.
I need the services to be able to communicate with each other, and some of them need to be publically accessible.
I keep seeing info about using either Service Discovery or a Load Balancer assigned to each service. I would like to try and avoid having to set up 6 load balancers as it's more expensive and more effort to maintain.

This is how I have set up Service Discovery currently:

- All Tasks are setup to use awsvpc
- All services have been set up to use Service Discovery (set up from within the Service Creation page)
- All services are sharing the same Namespace, and they're all using the A DNS Record

When I try to ping `<service_discovery_name>.<namespace>` from within one of the docker containers I do not get a response. However, I can successfully ping another container when pinging the private IP Address.

Can I achieve what I need to do with Service Discovery?
If so, how exactly do the containers communicate with each other?

Thanks heaps! Please let me know if I haven't provided enough info.

EDIT: Recreating the services and setting them up with a new Service Discovery seemed to resolve the issue. No idea why the old discovery didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked with  `dig <private name>`? Do you find correct resolution to privte IP addresses of the tasks?

Comment: Hi, have you enabled DNS support and DNS resolution in the Fargate VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: @mokugo-devops Hi, yes I have enabled them. DNS Resolution and DNS Hostnames are both enabled in the VPC. However, ClassicLink DNS Support is Disabled (not sure how to enable)

Comment: @Marcin am I supposed to run the Dig command from within one of the docker containers? If so, is there any other way I can verify the service name, because I am running Alpine docker containers and it's a pain to install bash on them.

Comment: You can go to Route53 and check if you have the A records there. So how do you `ping` the containers if not from inside the other containers? Form an instance?

Comment: @Marcin Under Route53 > Hosted Zones > [namespace_name] I can see the A records for each of my services and their correct private IPs.
I am opening shell (sh) on a docker container and running 'ping <service_discovery_name>.<namespace>'.
I can't run 'dig' because the dnsutils package isn't installed on the container.
Thanks for helping me by the way!

Comment: What you can do is to spin up an ec2 instance in the same subnet as your services, and test private name resolution on it. At least this way you will know if this is something at vpc level (if it does not work on instance) or Farget related only.

Comment: I've just changed the Launch Type on one of my services to EC2, then I SSHed into the EC2 instance that it sits on. 
I then ran the 'dig <service_discovery_name>.<namespace>' command for the Fargate Service and the EC2 service.
I don't really know how to read the response, but I can't see their matching private IPs. Here's the output: https://i.postimg.cc/SRTN5yYd/service-disco-dig.jpg

Comment: @Marcin, I've got no idea why, but I just recreated my services exactly the same but I set up a new Service Discovery, and now everything works. I can dig them and the IP gets resolved.  When comparing the old Service Discovery side by side with the new one they are the same, so I've got no idea why it started working.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to hear. I will make an answer if you dont mind for future  reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, the exact cause of the issue is **undetermined**. However, the problem was solved by creating a **new Service Discovery** in ECS.