# Communication between AWS Fargate Services not working even with route53 setup

Tags: aws-fargate

I have 2 services running in a single private vpc subnet (same available zone). Each service is based on a container here: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-microservices .

I've setup route53 service endpoints for both services.

When I run my tasks (each within their own service) service A times out calling service B over service B's route53 endpoint. Using localhost doesn't work because these containers are in separate services.

1. When I create a container for my task definition, I assign the port that my container is using (using port mapping field). However I notice in the console there is this note: "Host port mappings are not valid when the network mode for a task definition is host or awsvpc. To specify different host and container port mappings, choose the Bridge network mode."

Since I'm using Fargate I am using awsvpc mode. So is this telling my port mapping setting isnt doing anything ? Is that why my services are timing out ?

Then when I google bridge mode, this seems to tell me that awscpv networking mode support service discovery: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/amazon-ecs-service-discovery-supports-bridge-and-host-container-/

So how does "bridge mode" work here ? Why does port mapping field not work for awsvpc ?

Edit:

I read this [How to communicate between Fargate services on AWS ECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150562/how-to-communicate-between-fargate-services-on-aws-ecs) and he just says "I created a new service and things started working." That's a bit disheartening.

Edit2:

Yes my vpc has enabled dns resolution.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the security group on my service was only allowing http on port 80. That is the inbound rules the default SG that the service wizard gives you. I updated it to allow traffic on my container ports and they seem to be talking to each other now.

Comment: This was also my issue. I needed to use my own security group and not the default one...